# Undefined variable: _SESSION in Class

Tags: php, session

Strange Situation. I have a Projects Class which has the following constructor

```
public function __construct($db){
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->lang = strtolower($_SESSION['la']);
}
```

I'm using AJAX to call a simple get() function but the error returned is

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _SESSION in <b>D:\Sites\proman\class\Projects.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
```

In my index.php I have session_start() so that's not the problem. I can even print_r($_SESSION) in the construct method and i see the session variable of 'la'.##

I tried adding session_start() also to the top of my Projects.php class but then I get the warning that session has already started.

This is my session init at the top of index.php ##
it also set's a default language (la) variable if none is chosen by the user

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['la'])) $_SESSION['la'] = "EN";
?>
```

This is the output of the print_r() in the Projects Constructor ##
    Array ( [la] => FR )
Any idea whay might be going wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Could we see your `index.php` file ? Make sure `session_start()` is at the very top of this file.

Comment: And show us the `print_r($_SESSION)` output when put inside the constructor.

Comment: Are you sure that your Ajax call goes through `index.php`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _SESSION in <b>D:\Sites\proman\class\Projects.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
```

is the **result** of your ajax call. Right?

The issue is that you are missing `session_start()` in the file requested with ajax. I think the file is `Projects.php` in you class. Since you are using ajax, not `include/require` the `session_start()` on your index.php page is not sufficient. Separate `session_start()` is needed for the ajax page (Projects.php here).

Add a new `session_start()` on your ajax page(Projects.php) and let me know whether it fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi! I added the file to the file which requests the Projects.php file and now it's working. You were right, AJAX doesn't know about the session_ in the index.php. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the solution, great answer.